# Network Flow problem(Increasing the capacity of an arc by constant)

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

I would appreciate if someone give me a clue how I approach to answer this network flow problem question:

Let $D=(V,E)$, source $s$, sink $t$, and integral capacity function $c$. Suppose we increase the capacity on each arc by one. 
Characterize those networks in which the operation does not increase the maximum flow value by at least one.

Comment: Suppose there is a path from the source to the sink along which fluid is flowing in a maximum flow.  If the capacity of each arc along the path is increased by $1$, we can send an addition unit of fluid along the path from source to sink.

Comment: The question says, characterize those networks in which the operation does not increase the maximum flow value by at least one. I think yours is opposite, is that not?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if there is a non-zero maximum flow, increasing all the arc capacities will increase the maximum flow.